# Can Compiler Of different language share components

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science

I want to know that Can Compiler of Different Language share components,  please give briefly about above mentioned question. if its possible? then how?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are asking here. Are you asking about compiler toolchains using common components? In which case you might want to look at JVM or LLVM. Perhaps you meant compiled executables being able to use libraries written in other languages? Please be specific.

Comment: Oh come off it people. The question is clear enough, and the answer is 'yes'. `gcc` is a prime example: several front-ends for different languages (C, C++, Ada, ...); one back-end; and a vast RTL generation system for different CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

*gcc* is a prime example: several front-ends for different languages (C, C++, Ada, ...); one back-end; and a vast RTL generation system for different CPUs.